# Website URL shows server folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've accidentally replaced our website's htaccess file yesterday and messed a couple of things up. I've been able to get the site back online, however, now, [my site](http://gemdigitalagency.com) is showing the server's folder structure in the URL for all of the website's pages.

Desired:

```
http://gemdigitalagency.com/our-services
```

What is showing:

```
https://gemdigitalagency.com/production/gemdigitalagency/our-services/
```

I'd like to remove the /production/gemdigitalagency from the URL.

Here's what I have for htaccess (hosted in public_html):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gemdigitalagency\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gemdigitalagency.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?gemdigitalagency.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /production/gemdigitalagency/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?gemdigitalagency.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ production/gemdigitalagency/index.html [L]

ErrorDocument 400 /404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html

Options -Indexes
```

Could anyone please point me to the right direction?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We ended up removing a couple of things and adding an htaccess to the website's folder contents on the server.

htaccess in the public_html folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gemdigitalagency\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gemdigitalagency.com/$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html

Options -Indexes
```

htaccess in the website's folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gemdigitalagency\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gemdigitalagency\.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gemdigitalagency\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gemdigitalagency\.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect user to SSL secured web `http://...` onto `https://`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gemdigitalagency\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gemdigitalagency.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This is where is your main issue

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /production/gemdigitalagency/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ production/gemdigitalagency/index.html [L]
```

which tells apache to rewrite everything going on host `www.gemdigitalagency.com` OR `gemdigitalagency.com` (www is optional)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?gemdigitalagency.com$
```

to with something more in the URI

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
```

which is not actual filename or directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

rewrite to `/production/gemdigitalagency/$1` where the `$1` is anything behind a host (https://gemdigitalagency.com/something?get_param=1) the `$1` is `something?get_param=1` for example

try to change it to:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gemdigitalagency\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gemdigitalagency.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?gemdigitalagency.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?gemdigitalagency.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /index.html [L]

ErrorDocument 400 /404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the explanation! I've changed it to the above, but the website now shows up as 500 Internal Server Error. [See if it shows up like that for you.](http://gemdigitalagency.com)

Comment: I changed it back to the htaccess before, so the site is at least up. Any ideas what else we could try? Thanks again Jakub!

Comment: I will try to keep it in mind and simulate your issue on Friday evening CET. If I will be able to help you, I will update my answer and let you know.

Comment: Hey Jakub, thanks for taking a look. I had resolved my problem. Will post below!